# Windows authentication (SSO) for intranet users and form auth for internet users in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-7.0

I am developing an ASP.net core web application (.net 7). Some users will access this site using internal network (Intranet) and some use the Internet to access it.

I need to find a way to not prompt Windows Authentication mode for an Intranet user and display a form that allows for me to capture credentials and authenticate against active directory for an Internet user.

I've looked everywhere for answers but nothing i tried has worked yet.

Comment: Thats exact what Windows tries to prevent you to do: "allows for me to capture credentials and authenticate against active directory". By programming capturing, storing (?), and forwarding the credentials, you will create security issues in your system.

Answer (score 0):

This shall work i used this code for my app and it worked!

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // Authenticate against active directory or your custom authentication logic
            if (/* Authentication successful */)
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username), // Add additional claims if needed
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid credentials");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@model YourNamespace.LoginViewModel

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyScheme";
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddNegotiate("MyScheme", options =>
            {
                options.ForwardDefault = "MyFallbackScheme";
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "MyFallbackScheme";
            })
            .AddCookie("MyFallbackScheme", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            });

            // Other service configurations...

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // Other app configurations...

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Other middleware configurations...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```